# Store the contents in a combined file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

#### Assumption

I want to reference and match two files and add new columns and numbers to one of the files.

#### What we want to do

If the name in the "Name" column of the first file (wals_languages_joshi.csv) matches the name in the "name" column of the second file (Joshi2020_list.csv), the "score" column in the second file to the first file. (See below).

When this code is run, nothing is added to the newly added "name" and "score" columns.
I'd like to ask for your help. Thank you in advance.

#### Error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/carlobroschi_imac/Workspace/wals_and_joshi.py", line 8, in <module>
    after_pd = after_pd.capitalize()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5575, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'capitalize'
carlobroschi_imac@CarlonoiMac Workspace % python3 wals_and_joshi.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/carlobroschi_imac/Workspace/wals_and_joshi.py", line 8, in <module>
    after_pd = after_pd.str.capitalize()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5575, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
```

#### Source code

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.8
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd

before_pd = pd.read_csv('wals_languages_joshi.csv')
after_pd = pd.read_csv('Joshi2020_list.csv')

after_pd = after_pd.str.capitalize()
f=pd.merge(before_pd, after_pd, left_on='Name', right_on='Name', how='outer')

f.to_csv('result2.csv',index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

#### ideal output

```
Name,Family,Subfamily,Genus,Macroarea,ISO639P3code,score
Arapesh (Abu),Torricelli,,Kombio-Arapesh,,
Aari,Afro-Asiatic,Omotic,South Omotic,Africa,aiw,0
Abau,Sepik,,Upper Sepik,Papunesia,aau,0
Arabic (Chadian),Afro-Asiatic,,Semitic,Africa,shu
Abidji,Niger-Congo,,Kwa,Africa,abi
```

#### Files (wals_languages_joshi.csv，Joshi2020_list.csv)

```
Name,Family,Subfamily,Genus,Macroarea,ISO639P3code
Arapesh (Abu),Torricelli,,Kombio-Arapesh,,
Aari,Afro-Asiatic,Omotic,South Omotic,Africa,aiw
Abau,Sepik,,Upper Sepik,Papunesia,aau
Arabic (Chadian),Afro-Asiatic,,Semitic,Africa,shu
Abidji,Niger-Congo,,Kwa,Africa,abi
```

```
name,score
a-pucikwar,0
aari,0
a-pucikwar,0
abaza,0
abenaki,0
```

#### Additional information

iMac, Python3.9.12, VSCode

Comment: need `pd.merge(before_pd, after_pd, left_on='Name', right_on='name', how='outer')`

Comment: Thanks, but nothing is added to the newly added column.

Comment: So it means there is no match, maybe because lowercase `name` values?

Comment: So how can I solve this problem concretely?

Comment: hmm, `after_pd = after_pd.str.capitalize()` working?

Comment: No, there is some error message.

Comment: Maybe need `after_pd['name'] = after_pd['name'].str.capitalize()`